# Sharing a proxied university LAN connection via a TP-LINK TP-WR740N router

Tags: router, proxy, dhcp

I have access to university LAN that’s behind proxy and user-password authentication. They assign IP's via DHCP, so my IP changes all the time. Gateway, DHCP servers and DNS addresses remain constant. I want to share this connection via a [TP-LINK TP-WR740N](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-9_TL-WR740N.html) router.

So far I have tried the following:

1. Tried the quick setup, but router is detecting my connection as static.
2. In router admin -> Connections, there is a dynamic IP section, but it doesn’t allow setting dynamic values. I tried renewing but gateway and assigned IP’s remain `0.0.0.0`.
3. Did a factory reset and re-tried step 1.

This seems like a common requirement, so I am sure there is a way. What am I missing here ?

Comment: I will if I can't figure it out..it just seems like a trivial issue to me, so I wanted to fix it myself.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your University is limiting access by MAC addresses (ie limiting to known computers), so your device is not being given a DHCP lease when it requests it.   If thats the case, check if you modem supports MAC cloning (according to an online search it should).    You can also check by trying to connect a new/unsanctioned device directly to the network and see if it works.

Have you checked that the connection from the Uni is plugged into the WAN port - if its in a LAN port it won't work - and indeed this could cause issues for others.

Comment: It uses MAC authentication, so I used MAC cloning. Also, the connection is plugged into WAN port and on-router DHCP is disabled to avoid messing with the network.

Comment: You need to ENABLE DHCP on the router so it can give your computer a valid IP address unless you are using static IP's on your LAN.  The DHCP server should only work on the LAN interfaces.

Comment: Ohh..I was worried it will interfere with the main DHCP server. I will try and report back.